# compact framework merge datagrid cells

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, compact-framework

i couldn't find nothing useful for this problem

can anybody help me out

i'm using c#

Answer (score 1):

The compact framework is very limited. Consider yourself luck it has cells at all. No merging available.

Answer (score 0):

See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/fea3dcff-5447-450a-8f7c-bb1c4f63371d/

To summarize:

The DataGridView does not have any support for merging cells. You can custom paint content across cells, but apart from that you would have to do a lot of work and custom coding to produce merged editable cells.
-mark
DataGridView Program Manager
Microsoft
This post is provided "as-is"